# Assuming that indexing starts from zero, calculate the total of values at even index positions (1, 3, 5, …) in x86 assembly language in c++ compiler

Tags: assembly, x86

When I try to run my code with two sample arrays in godbolt c++ compiler where it's working fine with one array and showing wrong value for the other one. Could anyone please help me to find the sum of the even index positions(1,3,5,...) values.(Assume that indexing starts from zero(0).

Here is the code that I tried running,

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <cstdio>
#include <cassert>
#else
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#endif

int solution_for_grade_6(int const * arr, unsigned int arr_size)
{
    int result;

    __asm
    {
            mov ebx, 0;
            mov esi, [arr]; 
            mov ecx, [arr_size];

            jecxz emptyarr

        cycle:
            push ebx;
            mov eax, [ESI];
            mov ebx, 2;
            cdq
            idiv ebx;
            cmp edx, 0;
            pop ebx;
            je next;
            add ebx, dword ptr[ESI];

        next:
            add esi, 4;
            loop cycle;
            mov result, ebx;
        emptyarr:
    }

    return result;
}

// :::

int main()
{
    int test_result;

    // Change the count of elements and their values according to your task specifics:
    int test_arr1[] = { 0, 1000, 2250, -3000, 4444, 5678, 66543, 70, -80000, 900000 };

    test_result = solution_for_grade_6(test_arr1, sizeof(test_arr1)/sizeof(test_arr1[0]));

    // Use the function assert() to test for correctness:
    // assert(test_result == 0); // replace 0 with the expected result
    // And/or show the result:
    printf("Grade 6 result1 = %d\n", test_result);

    // To test for side cases, for the same grade level function you might need different input arrays, e.g.:
    int test_arr2[] = { 0, -1, 2, -3, 4, -5, 6, -7, 8, -9};

    test_result = solution_for_grade_6(test_arr2, sizeof(test_arr2)/sizeof(test_arr2[0]));
    // assert(test_result == 0); // replace 0 with the expected result
    // And/or show the result:
    printf("Grade 6 result2 = %d\n", test_result);

    // :::

    return 0;
}
```

Can you please solve this issue?

Comment: You are testing the values not the indices. In any case, the solution is not to divide but simply to iterate 2 items at a time (like climbing the stairs stepping on every second one).

Comment: I could be missing something, but 1,3,and 5 are odd.

Comment: @Jester I do not know how to test indices in this code. could you please help me?

Comment: @user4581301 , yes, 1,3,5  are odd values but the question is even index position where the indexing starts from 0. Like from the positions 0,1,2,3,4,5, even index position are 1,3,5

Comment: There is no need to test. Just increment by 2 elements (8 bytes) each time skipping the indices you do not want to process.

Comment: @user4581301: Yup, when you're counting from zero, the first element is at an even position.  0,2,4,8,... are the even elements of an array or SIMD vector or whatever.  1,3,5,7,... are the odd elements.  This assignment picked a really nonsensical way to describe the fact that they want every 2nd element starting from the second.  This convention leads to the fact that rounder numbers are the start of an aligned pair of elements.